# Render javascript for partial - Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm still relatively new to rails and getting used to a few things. Just a quick question really, I have an AJAX form (with :remote => true etc...) which works and sends the data to the server without a pageload.

My question is around the javascript file that can be used after the post. My partial is called '_newsomething.html.erb' and once it's posted I want to execute a javascript file - do these files have to be named after actions in the controller to sync and work properly in rails? At the moment I have a javascript file called 'create.js.erb' with just an javascript alert in it, but it's not firing.

e.g. do I need to have a partial called '_create.html.erb' and then a javascript file called 'create.js.erb'? Is there anyway of telling Rails where to go for a javascript file from within the controller?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Controller code below (very basic and generated at the moment)**

```
  def create
@snip = Snip.new(params[:snip])

respond_to do |format|
  if @snip.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@snip, :notice => 'Snip was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @snip, :status => :created, :location => @snip }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @snip.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: It might be helpful if you include your controller code. Specifically the create action that is getting called when you submit the remote form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller action you have to have:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { .... }
  format.js
end
```

The format.js is the important part. If Rails discovers that you are POSTing through AJAX, then it will render _create.js.erb partial.

Comment: Thanks mate - needed to make a couple of other minor tweeks but this did the trick, lovely stuff :).